# Flow reduction by removing a set of k edges

Tags: algorithms, network-flow

I am trying to find an algorithm which recieves as input:
1) a Flow network N(G,c,s,t) in which the capacity of an edge is either 0 or 1 (i.e. Exists or not).
2) a positive integer k

The output should be a set of k edges from G so that removing them (reducing their capacity to 0) will create a flow network with a minimal "max-flow" as possible.

After mauling it over for the last 3 hours, I am thinking it has to do with reducing those edges that are involved in the min-cut. Still I am not able to formulate an algorithm that of which correctness i can prove.

Thank you for any help in directing me to an answer.

EDIT: After further thought, I have found the min-cut edges by following this: (http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=maxFlow)

If i remove an edge that belongs to tthe min cut, i create a smaller cut and therefore a small flow (min-cut=max-flow).

If K>=(number of edges in the cut) then the flow will be 0, otherwise the flow will be the number of edges minus k.

Does that sound good? Do i need to prove something other than the correctness of min-cut=max-flow?